# Google cloud platform, no quota "GPUs (all regions)"

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I want to increase the "GPUs (all regions)", or `GPUS_ALL_REGIONS`, for a project on Google Cloud.

However, the option is not in the "Metric" list on the "Quotas" page of the project.

Does anyone of you know how this can happen? For other projects I have on the same Billing Account, the option is present in the list:

- Present: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6iQaJ.png
- Not present: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FAhJ9.png

Please keep in mind that the Compute Engine is enabled on both.

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Do you have activate the same API? Is a project be in a Alpha program?

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your concern, quota is based on reputation. You may find some project which has this metric “GPUs (all regions)”and some other does not. The old project might have this metric but most of the time new projects does not have.

Besides this, you can submit a quota increase request for each region and dedicated team can assist you for your concern.Also, please make sure GPU type is available in the requested [region](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/gpus/).  Please use this [link](https://cloud.google.com/compute/quotas#requesting_additional_quota) to submit your request